# What are some libraries/ways of manipulating MSWord formats in Android?

Tags: java, android, apache

I've been working on ways to load/edit and then create .docx files for the past week now. I just need to manipulate text within a template and later down the track add pictures. I've tried the following libraries and will explain where i got to for each.

Apache POI (library for android https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx)
I imported all the libraries necessary and was able to create an empty .docx then when i went to load a docx then write it again and recieved this error

1. Apache POI (library for android https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx)

> `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnote.init(XWPFFootnote.java:64)`

I know that it will lead me around a circle again and will result in someone saying (these classes can't be used in android). The link is only made for xlsx (an excel format). I've already tried.... "import org.apache.poi.usermodel.*;" This is because the classes used for the function are designed for not android and reference the JDK classes

2. Docx4j (android branch)

I was able to get write the load and save code but it hits this error as soon as it needs the JAXB.jar, which i had imported (its this one ae-jaxb-2.2.5 for android) but the problem is that it's still trying to read the javax folder in the java JDK.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
```

Please only respond to my errors if you've experienced my trauma and are living proof that this is possible. Otherwise please do recommend some other libraries or ways around me getting a Document manipulation function happening.

I'm using java 1.7_79 SDK and that latest android studio.

What are some libraries I can use to manipluate MSWord formats in Android?
Else, how, other than editting straight xml copies of the template can I program a way to alter text in a document from android?